# NSButton state not changing

Tags: swift, nsbutton

The following code works perfect in my sandbox:

```
@IBAction func filterClicked(sender: NSButton) {
  println(sender.state)
  if let clickEvent = NSApp.currentEvent! {
    if Int(clickEvent.modifierFlags.rawValue) & Int(NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask.rawValue) != 0 {
      if sender.state == NSOffState {
        sender.state == NSOnState
      }
    }
  }
  println(sender.state)
}
```

The connected button is an On-Off button. So when it's on and I ctrl-click it it will stay on.

Unfortunately in my app where I really need this it does not work. I checked that in both sandbox and prod app the bindings/settings are identically for both buttons. The debugger shows that

```
        sender.state == NSOnState
```

is simply not performed. `state` stays `NSOffState`. Gnawing my keyboard did not help. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not assign any value to the button state.

```
sender.state = NSOnState
```

Update for Swift 4.2

```
sender.state = NSControl.StateValue.on
```

Comment: OMG! I sent that as bug report that the compiler should issue a warning in this case. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Changing state of a Radio Button (Check state) for swift 4:

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkedButton: NSButton!

checkedButton.state = NSControl.StateValue.off // State = off

checkedButton.state = NSControl.StateValue.on  // State = on
```

Comment: They change the syntax more often than their underwear :-/

Answer (score 0):

I know this already has an accepted answer, but sharing my scenario in case it trips up someone else:

I had the same issue where I couldn't programmatically set the state for my button in a custom table view cell.  MY issue, is that I was trying to set the state when my table first created the cell.  Instead, I had to make sure to override the layout method in my custom cell and set the state there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in a CollectionViewItem...
I had an outlet for the favouriteButton...

```
class PictureCollectionViewItem: XCollectionViewItem
{
    @IBOutlet var thumbnailView: NSImageView!
    @IBOutlet var tagsView: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet var favouriteButton: NSButton!
    ... 
}
```

I had linked the outlet to the Collection View Item object[image]

but NOT linked it to the File's Owner... [image]

As soon as I linked it to the File's Owner as well, ... it all worked.